# Two bootstrap in a single page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to use two bootstrap(Twitter Bootstrap and "Paper" bootstrap) for a single webpage

But when I include both css and js files, Second css and js files overrides..
Is there any way to include both bootstrap in a single Page?

Comment: You can make custom bootstrap from site with only necessary elements.

Comment: i have a web page that uses default bootstrap and the page has a button.When i click the button it needs to open a modal and that modal and all inside it should be made under "Paper" bootstrap

Comment: You can just copy up the class of respective elements with their dimensions from paper bootstrap,  as you only want a smallset of features this will be good in terms of optimization too

Comment: is there anyother way becoz that modal should have many functionalities like toggle button .chk box,etc

Comment: you can change the classes on the second bootstrap but that will be changed back when the bootstrap is upgraded :P

Comment: There is not a pre-made solution for this.  And the reason why i told you for taking up classes from paper is because you can use cdnjs facility for your bootstrap to stay consistent.  You can easily get checkboxes,  toggles from paper,  follow documentation and pick up their classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could recompile the LESS from paper to target the ID of the modal so the css would only apply to that modal.

```
#modal-id{ /*all bootstrap css for paper*/}
```

You would most likely need to change the js file too. You could just take the function that Paper has that Bootstrap doesn't.

Is a lot of overhead having two full versions though so I recommend picking only the bits you need. Is time consuming but is better than making the user waiting for massive loading times.